# SWIG: Unable to ignore a method in a C++ class

Tags: c++, swig

I'm trying to wrap a C++ library using Swig, and I'm having trouble with an overloaded method (and it doesn't help that I haven't touched C++ in 18 years :)

Here's a much simplified class structure:

```
class TView : public TObject, public TStreamable {
    public:
        virtual TPalette& getPalette() const;
}

class TGroup : public TView {
    // ...
}

class TWindow: public TGroup {
    virtual TPalette& getPalette() const;
}
```

The swig file (again, simplified, looks like this):

```
%module(directors="1") tvision
%feature("director") TApplication;
%feature("director") TProgram;
%feature("director") TProgInit;
%feature("director") TWindow;
%feature("director") TWindowInit;
%feature("director") TView;
%feature("director") TGroup;
// Obviously a shotgun approach hoping one of these works :P
%rename ("$ignore") TWindow::getPalette; 
%ignore TWindow::getPalette; 
%rename ("getPalette2") "TWindow::getPalette";
//...
%include "tv/view.h"
%include "tv/group.h"
%include "tv/window.h"
```

When I generate the Java wrappers and try to compile it, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project tvsample: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /home/jdlee/src/turbovision/swig/src/generated/java/com/steeplesoft/turbovision/internal/tvisionJNI.java:[1348,45] incompatible types: short cannot be converted to com.steeplesoft.turbovision.internal.TPalette
[ERROR] /home/jdlee/src/turbovision/swig/src/generated/java/com/steeplesoft/turbovision/internal/TWindow.java:[129,16] getPalette() in com.steeplesoft.turbovision.internal.TWindow cannot override getPalette() in com.steeplesoft.turbovision.internal.TView
[ERROR]   return type short is not compatible with com.steeplesoft.turbovision.internal.TPalette
```

Two things. The first is that TWindow::getPalette should be ignored, but it's not. The second is that SWIG is generating this Java method:

```
public short getNumber() {
  return tvisionJNI.TWindow_number_get(swigCPtr, this);
}
```

Does anybody have an answer for either issue? Ideally, there should be a single TWindow#getPalette() method that returns TPalette. If I can fix that, it might fix the ignore issue, as I'm only trying to ignore the method to see if I can just get past the compilation issue.

Help? Please? :)

Comment: I don’t see any `%ignore` statement in your SWIG code. How have you marked the method to be ignored? You also haven’t explained how SWIG got the `number_get` or `getNumber` method inside C++. Is there a corresponding part in your C++ code, like a method or a public property? I think the code posted in the question as of now is _over_-simplified.

Comment: You're right. I forgot to include that. :) 
%rename ("$ignore") TWindow::getPalette;

%ignore TWindow::getPalette;

%rename ("getPalette2") "TWindow::getPalette";

I've tired with and without quotes and parens with no discernible change.

Comment: Missed the second part there. I'm not sure *how* it got the short method. The full headers are https://bitbucket.org/jdlee/turbovision/src/master/library/include/tv/window.h and https://bitbucket.org/jdlee/turbovision/src/master/library/include/tv/view.h